# mod_rewrite changes the current dir

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a php file that loads an article from a db based on the given variables. There is also an .htacces file in the root of the site. I used this in the htaccess to redirect

> RewriteRule
>   ^articles/([a-zA-Z0-9-_\s]+).html$
>   template/index.php?action=viewarticle&alias=$1

after redirecting, the page shows fine but the html in the page goes wrong, for example:

`media/2011/02/21/logos.jpg` turns in to `articles/media/2011/02/21/logos.jpg`

This happens because the htacces is redirecting. Is there anyway to do this redirect while keeping the root dir unchanged?

Comment: Try adding like RewriteBase /

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This happens coz the htacces is redirecting.

No, this happens because the browser thinks that

```
example.com/articles/my_article.html
```

is a resource in the `/articles` sub-directory, and treats all relative URLs as relative to `/articles`.

There is no way to change that behaviour.

You will need to start using absolute image references, or relative image references that consider the additional directory:

```
<img src="/media/2011/02/21/logos.jpg">      <------ recommended
<img src="../media/2011/02/21/logos.jpg">
```

you could also use `<base>` as suggested by @Boris but absolute paths (or full URLs) are a vastly cleaner solution to the problem in my opinion.

Comment: You are correct. But i dont want to change the html (i cant change it anyway coz its loaded from a db which i cant edit) The thing i did was user a str_replace to replace all the "media/" with "../media/" in the html before showing it in the page and it worked perfectly. Thank you everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

First, what do you mean by "html in the pages goes wrong":

- Is it the link showed in the status bar?
- Is it the actual href? If it is, you probably use some view helper which construct your "base url"
- Maybe you "link" your resource without specifing an absolute path (using /), then your resource are "relatively" linked to current page (/articles/)

**.htaccess don't change anything in your code.**

There is an html element which allow you to define base url used everywhere in your page.

```
<base href="/root" />
```

if you have for example `<a href="/articles/12">Article 12</a>` then when clicking on the link, you will redirect to /root/articles/12

Comment: Doesn't deserve a downvote, it's a perfectly viable answer (although I personally dislike `base` with a vengeance)

Comment: Weird to downvoted without any reason, but I need to agree with you Pekka, I don't recommend <base> either, and rather use absolute URI, but in some case (with ModX CMS) I had to use it, but it need to be used carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Also, mixing Pekka's answer with Boris', you should define somewhere in your application which is the root path of your application and output all paths as absolute, prepending the base dir you defined earlier.

for example: in config.inc.php

```
define("ROOT_URI", "http://myserver.com/myapp");
```

everywhere:

```
<img src="<?php echo ROOT_URI;?>/media/2011/02/21/logos.jpg
```

This is like using the `base` element as Boris suggested, without using it (I also dislike `base`), and makes your application able to work in whatever folder under the webserver it is stored.

Comment: Do you use such approach yourself? Care to post here a link?

Comment: Yes, I use it all the time. A link to what? I think the reasoning behind that it's pretty clear in my answer.

Comment: a link to the site where such method is used. you know, it's extremely rare to see a site that uses full URL for the local links. So, I'm just curious.

Comment: ah ok. Well, I don't use the full URL for the local links, but I thought it would be more clear here if I put it up this way. I actually skip the http://myserver.com part. You can see this at http://www.pue.es/continua/ (you'll see some links with the http part, but that's because the same code generates the webpage and the newsletter sent to subscribers).

Comment: I use the same thing all the time. Why on earth would one want to downvote this?